# Can we hide certain rows in ng-grid based on its values?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an array of values.

```
Questions = [
           {Name:"First", Status:"Valid"},
           {Name:"Second", Status:"Invalid"},
           {Name:"Third", Status:"Valid"},
           {Name:"Fourth", Status:"Invalid"}
           ];
```

I can display these in the ng-grid. But can I hide a row if the value of Status is Invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `filterOptions` property of `gridOptions`

```
$scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText: 'Status:Valid',
    useExternalFilter: true
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'Questions',
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
};
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But without useExternalFilter: true.